# Use distance between y-axis ticks as variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

Is there a way to use the distance between the ticks in the y-axis as variable within ggplot function?

I want to plot an annotation whose y-coordinate can be "responsive" to the y-axis scale of a graph.

In the example below, I would like var1 to be the distance between successive y-axis ticks as taken from the parameters of the specific graph, and not a user-defined constant.

Data:

```
EXse2<- data.frame(wk=c(1,2), EX=c(4.457143, 2.580952), se=c(0.4209481,0.5519333))
```

Code:

```
var1<- 0.1
labEX<- "\u002A\u002A"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(EXse2, aes(x=factor(wk), y=EX, group=1))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=EX-se, ymax=EX+se), width=.2, size=1)+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  annotate("text", label=labEX, x=1.5, y=(mean(EXse2$EX[1:2])+var1))+
  xlab("period")+
  ylab(expression(bar(EX)))+
  theme(
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "#d9d9d9"), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#bfbfbf"),  
        axis.line = element_line()
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating to plot first, extracting the tick distances with `ggplot_build` and then add the annotation:

```
library(ggplot2)

EXse2<- data.frame(wk=c(1,2), EX=c(4.457143, 2.580952), se=c(0.4209481,0.5519333))
labEX<- "\u002A\u002A"

#first, put your plot in p1
p1 <-
ggplot(EXse2, aes(x=factor(wk), y=EX, group=1))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=EX-se, ymax=EX+se), width=.2, size=1)+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  # I HAVE REMOVED THE ANNOTATE HERE
  xlab("period")+
  ylab(expression(bar(EX)))+
  theme(
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "#d9d9d9"), 
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#bfbfbf"),  
    axis.line = element_line()
  )

# extract axis limits
yminticks <- ggplot_build(p1)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.minor_source
# subtract first tick from second
var1 <- yminticks[2] - yminticks[1]

# and now add the annotate and plot
p1 + 
  annotate("text", label=labEX, x=1.5, y=(mean(EXse2$EX[1:2])+var1))
```